# Border style is not working in Internet explorer 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I have created a toggle-button that is not working in the IE-browser. I have doubts regarding the web-kit appearance and the border.

Here is a working snippet of my code:

```css
.contain {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 48px;
    height: 24px;
    background: #d6d6d6;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.checkbox {
    position: absolute;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: -5px;
    left: -10px;
    outline: none;
}

.checkbox:checked {
    left: 20px;
}
```

```html
 <label class="contain" >
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
 </label>
```

The border is fine in Chrome but in the Internet-Explorer the border-radius is not applied.

Comment: ok go to settings then select comptability view settings and see if display internat sites is checked

Comment: did you see if its checked?

Comment: yes it checked.

Comment: ok remove the check and restart your browser

Comment: and plz tell me if it works

Comment: no its not working

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the problem is with the `.checkbox` element, you haven't specified a border color for it which might be why you aren't seeing the border.

You could add it at the end of the `border` property, like this:

```
.checkbox {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -10px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  outline: none;
  background: white
}
```

Or you could split the `border` property into `border-width`, `border-style` and `border-color` properties, like this:

```
.checkbox {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -10px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  outline: none;
  background: white
}
```

Another thing you could try to do is make the border thicker, by changing the border's width (`1px`) to `2px`/`3px`.

Good luck.

Comment: Im getting a rectangle box instead of checkbox style

Comment: Borders are square by default, if you're looking for rounded borders, try using `border-radius: 4px;` (or tweaking that value) to get a *"rounded"* look.

Comment: I understand the result you're getting but I can't help you if you don't describe the result you want, if you want a circle instead of a square, use `border-radius: 50%;` to make it round.

Comment: I want circle instead of box , you can see code snippet above

Comment: Add `border-radius: 50%;` to `.checkbox` to turn it into a circle.

Comment: yes i have already done that .I works in chrome but in IE im getting Box

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
```

to the checkbox class